# How can I return UTC time?

Tags: datetime, timezone

Using, for instance, {current_time} you get the time according to your server timezone setting. I see I can format it with {current_time format="{DATE_COOKIE}"} to get a result in UTC, but I need it in another format than cookie.

I know I can write a plugin or some direct PHP to pull it out, but is there anything within what EE gives us to return the UTC time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply your own custom format if you need something specific.

You can find details on how to do it in the docs here:

[Date Variable Formatting](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html)

If you need to do something more specialised you could maybe try [Low Nice Date](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date/docs) that allow you to localise the date.

Comment: I'm familiar with this, but the way I'm reading it, {current_time} will always return time in the server's time (e.g. UTC-05 for Eastern Standard Time). But to get time in UTC, there isn't anything there, is there?

Comment: You are right, sorry, I read you question as a formatting issue. If you need to localise the date to the viewer you could try the add-on I've added to my answer, it might be of use.